# MacBook running Snow Leopard does not remember WEP password

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-snow-leopard, wep

I have a MacBook Pro5,5 running OS X 10.6.4.

I can connect to a certain WLAN using AirPort with a WEP password successfully, but the password is not remembered after each disconnection.

What's more, I do not even find an option to *say* that it should be remembered and unsurprisingly, the keychain has no entry pertaining to this connection.

How can I make my MacBook remember a WEP password (using Snow Leopard)?

I don't know if any of this is relevant, but for full disclosure:

This computer had the hard disk changed a year ago and a problematic backup from the old hard disk restored in an unconventional way. The hard disk change involved an upgrade from leopard to snow leopard, so the older entries in AirPort and KeyChain have been made using leopard.

Comment: Is this only affecting one specific WiFi network or all? Can you change the WEP password, or even change authentication to WPA? Can you remove the network from the list of remembered ones in *System Preferences » Network* and then try connecting again?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to another WiFi network for at least another week, and I have to use the WEP password here. I can remove the network and add it again, but when I enter the password in the System Preferences and press "Save", it then does not save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved and I want to describe the issue for others with the same problem:

The date of the system was set to 2001 (due to the hard disk change) and correcting it solved the WEP password issue (and many other minor issues).

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences>Network>Advanced>Wi-Fi

Delete that network from the list of preferred networks.

Then, rejoin the network from the menu bar. It should have an option to "Remember this Network." Check that box and see if that solved your problem.